# XSLT 3.0 More than 3 conditions on <xsl:choose> break streamability

Tags: xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I encountered a strange issue while I was trying to build an XSLT stylesheet that takes a parameter and applies appropriate templates based on a string value of that parameter. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="3.0" default-mode="s">

    <xsl:mode name="s" streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
    <xsl:mode name="ns" streamable="no"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="TemplateName" as="xs:string"/>

    <xsl:template match='/' mode="s">
        <File>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="s"/>
        </File>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Employee">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$TemplateName = 'Template1'">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Template1"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$TemplateName = 'Template2'">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Template2"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$TemplateName = 'Template3'">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Template3"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$TemplateName = 'Template4'">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Template4"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Template1">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Template2">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Template3">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Template4">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Everything works without any issues as long as I have only 3 "xsl:when" conditions in my "xsl:choose" code. As soon as I add the 4th condition:

```
<xsl:when test="$TemplateName = 'Template4'">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Template4"/>
</xsl:when>
```

I receive the following error:

> Template rule is declared streamable but it does not satisfy the streamability rules. * There is more than one consuming operand: {xsl:apply-templates} on line 25, and {xsl:apply-templates} on line 28

I am using Saxon-EE 9.7.0.19.

What is causing this issue? Is there any other way to apply templates dynamically based on input parameter?

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Employee>
        <Template1>SomeData1</Template1>
        <Template2>SomeData2</Template2>
        <Template3>SomeData3</Template3>
        <Template4>SomeData4</Template4>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <Template1>SomeData1</Template1>
        <Template2>SomeData2</Template2>
        <Template3>SomeData3</Template3>
        <Template4>SomeData4</Template4>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <Template1>SomeData1</Template1>
        <Template2>SomeData2</Template2>
        <Template3>SomeData3</Template3>
        <Template4>SomeData4</Template4>
    </Employee>
</Root>
```

Comment: I am kind of confused that you use a parameter named `TemplateName` yet you do an `xsl:apply-templates select` and `xsl:template match` based on the name which seems a child element selection. Anyway, XSLT 3 knows static parameters you can use with shadow attributes so try whether `<xsl:param name="TemplateName" as="xs:string" static="yes"/>` and a single `<xsl:apply-templates _select="{$TemplateName}"/>` works. As an alternative, you could use `<xsl:apply-templates select="*[name() = $TemplateName]"/>`.

Comment: Keep in mind that static parameters need to be set from the API in a different way than normal ones so if you run Saxon with code you will need to use e.g.http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.7/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XsltCompiler.html#setParameter(net.sf.saxon.s9api.QName,%20net.sf.saxon.s9api.XdmValue)

Comment: Thank you @MartinHonnen. I added the input XML to my original question. I ended up using your second solution, i.e. `<xsl:apply-templates select="*[name() = $TemplateName]"/>` Sorry, names of my parameter and templates might have been a little confusing indeed. Would you mind adding your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as the solution?

Comment: I have tried your code with the current stable release 9.9 and there it works so if you can move to that version. 9.7 is too old anyway as 9.8 was the first release to implement the final XSLT 3 spec.

Comment: It seems using a static parameter and then a shadow attribute `<xsl:apply-templates _select="{$TemplateName}"/>` does work with 9.7.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to move to Saxon 9.9, as I am using a tool called Workday Studio that have v9.7 built-in. I tried that static parameter as well and it doesn't work in both Oxygen and Workday Studio, as Oxygen is showing the following error: _An empty sequence is not allowed as the value of variable $TemplateName_

Answer (score 0):

Please try it on a more recent Saxon release (9.9 or 10.0). The streaming capabilities in the product advanced considerably since 9.7 was released back in 2015. (The XSLT 3.0 spec wasn't even published then.)